# Data inside a function (package creation)

Tags: r

If I need to use a data set inside a function (as a lookup table) inside of a package I'm creating do I need to explicitly load the data set inside of the function?

The function and the data set are both part of my package.

Is this the correct way to use that data set inside the function:

```
foo <- function(x){
    x <- dataset_in_question
}
```

or is this better:

```
foo <- function(x){
    x <- data(dataset_in_question)
}
```

or is there some approach I'm not thinking of that's correct?

Comment: Mhh...I would use apply functions in the function instead and the use the function on the data set, but perhaps this is not an option in this case...

Comment: I'm almost certain it's option (1). AFAIK, you use `data()` for its side effects, not its return value. In fact, the return value of `data()` is simply the name of the dataset, not the actual variable. Try, for example, `x <- data(iris)` and see what happens.

Comment: If you're only using the dataset as a lookup table and not changing it, is there a need to create a new identical object? If there is a need, you could consider adding the table as a formal argument to your function (`x = dataset_in_question`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can just place the data set as a .rda file in the R folder as described by Hadley here: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data-sysdata

Matthew Jockers uses this approach in the **syuzhet** package for data sets including the `bing` data set as seen at ~line 452 here: https://github.com/mjockers/syuzhet/blob/master/R/syuzhet.R

`bing` is not available to the user but is to the package as demonstrated by: `syuzhet:::bing`

Essentially, the command `devtools::use_data(..., internal = TRUE)` will set everything up in the way it's needed.

Comment: use_data is now deprecated

Comment: @jzadra no biggie just been moved to the **usethis** package as `usethis::use_data`

Answer (score 12):

There was a [recent discussion](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e17/devel/12/04/0864.html) about this topic (in the context of package development) on R-devel, numerous points of which are relevant to this question:

1. If only the options you provide are applicable to your example R himself (i.e., [Brian Ripley](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e17/devel/12/04/0865.html)) tells you to do:

   ```
   foo <- function(x){
      data("dataset_in_question")
   }
   ```
2. This approach will however throw a NOTE in R CMD check which can be avoided in upcoming versions of R (or currently R devel) by using the `globalVariables()` function, [added by John Chambers](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/30882)
3. The 'correct' approach (i.e., the one advocated by [Brian Ripley](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e17/devel/12/04/0868.html) and [Peter Dalgaard](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e17/devel/12/04/0869.html)) would be to use the LazyData option for your package. See [this section of "Writing R Extensions"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages).

Btw: I do not fully understand how your first approach should work. What should `x <- dataset_in_question` do? Is `dataset_in_question` a global Variable or defined previously?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was necessary to use `get()` additionally to `LazyData: true` in `DESCRIPTION` file (see postig by [@Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289572/henrik) point 3) to get rid of the NOTE `no visible binding for global variable ...`. My R version is `3.2.3`.

```
foo <- function(x){
    get("dataset_in_question")
}
```

So LazyData makes `dataset_in_question` directly accessible (without using `data("dataset_in_question", envir = environment())`) and `get()` is to satisfy `R CMD check`

HTH